# How to run a playbook task based on OS type in ansible?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, ansible

I have written a playbook task in ansible. I am able to run the playbook on linux end.

```
- name: Set paths for go
      blockinfile:
        path: $HOME/.profile
        backup: yes
        state: present
        block: |
          export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
          export GOPATH=$HOME/go
          export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$HOME/.fabdep/config

    - name: Load Env variables
      shell: source $HOME/.profile
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      register: source_result
      become: yes
```

As in linux we have `.profile` in home directory but in Mac there is no `.profile` and `.bash_profile` in macOS.

So I want to check if os is Mac then path should be `$HOME/.bash_profile` and if os is linux based then it should look for `$HOME/.profile`.

I have tried adding

```
when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release == 'precise'
```

But it does not work firstly and also it is length process. I want to get  path based on os in a variable and use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution this way. I added `gather_facts:true` at top of yaml file and it started working. I started using variable as `ansible_distribution`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this is to add a conditional `when` to the task in question. For example:

```yaml
- name: Install a few more tools
  become: yes
  apt:
    state: latest
    pkg:
    - bat
    - ripgrep
  when:
  - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Ubuntu" or ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'Pop!_OS'
  - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "20"
```

The above example would install the `bat` and `ripgrep` packages only when the OS is either Ubuntu or Pop!_OS, and the OS major version is 20 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to *include_vars* from files. See example below

```
- name: "OS specific vars (will overwrite /vars/main.yml)"
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
        - "default.yml"
      paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars"
      skip: true

- name: Set paths for go
  blockinfile:
    path: "$HOME/{{ my_profile_file }}"
[...]
```

In the playbooks' directory create directory *vars* and create files

```
# cat var/Ubuntu.yml
my_profile_file: ".profile"

# cat var/macOS.yml
my_profile_file: ".bash_profile"
```

Comment: I am not able to relate this with above playbook task I created. Can you relate this above task playlist I posted.Because I am getting started with Ansiblle

Comment: This is certainly one of the better ways to solve the problem, but you are probably going to need to expand the answer with an example to make it connect to the question.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you have troubles update your question with  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed hosts with different OS, group them by OS in your inventory:

```
[Ubuntu]
ubu1
ubu2

[RHEL6]
RH6_1

[RHEL7]
RH7_1
RH7_2
```

Comment: This works, but will become outdated as upgrades happen. Instead, the other answers use the Ansible feature to detect the OS, so the host selection will always be accurate.